# Table not updating when trigger is fired

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have 2 tables:

Employees(Employee_ID, First_name, Last_name, Email, Hire_date, Department_ID)

Departments(Department_ID, Department_name, Total_employees).

I have created trigger that fires after inserting an employee to employees table. It increases the total_employees column by 1 for :new inserted Department_ID.

Trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER emp_count_department
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON EMPLOYEES
for each row
DECLARE
    counter NUMBER;
BEGIN
    if inserting then
        select total_employees into counter
        from departments
        where department_id = :new.department_id;

        update departments
        set total_employees = counter+1
        where department_id = :new.department_id;

    elsif deleting then
        select total_employees into counter
        from departments
        where department_id = :old.department_id;

        update departments
        set total_employees = counter-1
        where department_id = :old.department_id;
    end if;
END;
```

When I try to insert an employee, it is inserted but it doesn't increase total_employees by 1 in departments table. When I try to insert an employee with a department_ID that doesn't exist in departments table, it gives me error. So the trigger is working but not increasing the total numbers by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER emp_count_department
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON EMPLOYEES
for each row
BEGIN
    if inserting then
        update departments
        set total_employees = total_employees+1
        where department_id = :new.department_id;

    elsif deleting then
        update departments
        set total_employees = total_employees-1
        where department_id = :old.department_id;
    end if;
END;
```

Comment: Then you need to provide [mcve]. That answer works for me and @pmdba. You need to show exactly what you are executing, what results you are getting and what you are expecting.  Just saying "it is not working" is completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

I did simple testing of your code in Oracle 11g and it seems to work.
Please check if you missed in adding information.

```
 create table emp1(emp_id number ,dept_id number);

 create table dept1 (dept_id number ,total_emp number);

    CREATE OR replace TRIGGER emp_count_dept
      AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON emp1
      FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        counter NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        IF inserting THEN
          UPDATE dept1
          SET    total_emp = total_emp + 1
          WHERE  dept_id = :new.dept_id;
        ELSIF deleting THEN
          UPDATE dept1
          SET    total_emp = total_emp - 1
          WHERE  dept_id = :old.dept_id;
        END IF;
    END; 

    insert into dept1 values(10,10);

    insert into emp1 values(10,10);

    select * from dept1;

    DEPT_ID TOTAL_EMP
        10  11
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an important use case, what if the employees table is updated and the dept_id changes.  To expand upon the answer @pmdba gave, I think the following code would work best.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emp_count_dept
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF DEPT_ID OR DELETE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.dept_id IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE departments d
    SET d.total_employees = NVL(d.total_employees, 0)+1
    WHERE d.department_id = :new.dept_id;
  END IF;

  IF :old.dept_id IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE departments d
    SET d.total_employees = d.total_employees - 1
    WHERE d.department_id = :old.dept_id;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

This takes care of `UPDATE` statements now.  And also takes care of the first `INSERT` for a given department (If you didn't initialize all departments.total_employee to 0 when you created them).

I also created this DBFiddle demonstrating the functionality (And why you need the `NVL` function or to default your TOTAL_EMPLOYEES column to 0) ([Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=74aa196eb1ab453edb994b721b616a85))